# Fixing concurrency issues in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

Yesterday I had a job interview with some technical questions. Sadly I failed it... 
There was an interesting question on the test with a code-snip I couldn't resolve, but still very excited about the resolution. I didn't get any explanation from the company. Literally was hard to sleep last night. Can you guys help we with some ideas?

The question:

Fix threading issues in servlet code efficiently.  Submit modified code-snip:

```
public class CachedServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private int cacheHits;
    private int lastId;
    private String lastResult;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String result = null;
        int id = extractFromRequest(request);
        if ((id == lastId) && (lastResult != null)) {
            result = lastResult;
            cacheHits++;
        } else {
            result = doTimeConsumingCalculation(id);
            lastId = id;
            lastResult = result;
        }
        encodeIntoResponse(response, result);
    }
```

Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: Your three class variables are critical section that you need to protect from threading issue/concurrent request. Servlets are not thread safe by default.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your query.

Comment: Your 3 fields are not protected against unsynchronized access. All 3 of them get written in your method, those write-accesses need to be synchronized in order to prevent two concurrent calls from writing them at the same time, leading into the typical issues with _weirdly wrong_ values.

Comment: In addition to the three fields not being threadsafe, I suspect the real point of the question is to avoid the time-consuming computation being triggered a second time while the first computation is still "in-flight" (rather than waiting for that one to complete and pick up the same result). And of course the need to to atomically set `lastId` and `lastResult` together and not end up with a weird mix.